# Tachar título (h2) a "mano alzada"

Tags: javascript, html, css

¿Sería posible tachar un texto (por ejemplo un h2) simulando una línea a mano 
alzada?

Es decir, no busco la propiedad css de tachado de un texto (text-decoration), sino algo más "humanizado" por así decirlo.

He pensado en poner una imágen png encima con una ralla pintada en algún editor, pero no se si es una buena idea...

Mi idea es que aparezca el texto y luego con javascript, esa línea lo tache.

¿Alguien sabe de algún ejemplo? o, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto. Con Canvas podrás hacer algo como lo que buscas https://stackoverflow.com/q/4627133/761181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te pongo una solución solo por CSS, sin JS. 
Después de tres segundos se traza una raya en las palabras que hayas puesto dentro de un `span`. Utilizo `span` para que puedas tachar cualquier texto sin cambiar su aspecto

```css
div{
width:100%;
}
span{ 
position:relative;
}
span:before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
  position:absolute;
  width:0%;
  height:100%;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-position:left center;
  background-size:20px auto;
   animation: draw 1s 1;
 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw {
from { width:0%;}
to { width:100%}
}
@keyframes draw {
from { width:0%;}
to { width:100%}
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et <h2><span>dolore magna aliqua</span></h2>. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate <span>velit esse cillum</span> dolore
eu
<div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, justo lo que necesitaba!

Answer (score 4):

Podrías hacerlo con javascript, con la función [`.strike()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/strike) y ejecutar un intervalo para que lo haga con cada string hasta finalizar de recorrerlo. De la siguiente manera:

```js
// función para el tachado
function crossOut() {
  var text = document.querySelector('.crossout');
  var originalText = text.innerText;
  var textLength = originalText.length;

  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // termino el intervalo una vez que termine todo el texto
    if (i == textLength) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    // texto tachado
    var crossOutText = originalText.substring(0, i).strike();
    // texto no tachado
    var leftText = originalText.substring(i);
    
    // reemplazo el texto original
    text.innerHTML = crossOutText + leftText;
    i++;
    
    // tiempo de intervalos en milisegundos
  }, 25);
}

// ejecuto la función
crossOut();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
}

#container .crossout {
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="crossout">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga porro voluptate officia maxime! Beatae, iusto. Nam consectetur eligendi possimus ipsum necessitatibus eveniet perferendis excepturi magni illo! Recusandae voluptas consequatur quia.</p>
</div>
```

---

Te dejo el [codepen](https://codepen.io/kleith/pen/KRJaPe) por si querés probar algunas otras cosas o cambiar el intervalo y probar como cambia.